# Split XML file to multiple files javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a big XML file,which i want to split in several files based on element count.
The code below divides the file depending on the batch size what is good but it throws it on one split xml 'test1.xml'. I don't really know how to split it to throw it into many files. Any ideas?

```
const XmlSplit = require("xmlsplit");
const fs = require("fs");

const xmlsplit = new XmlSplit(batchSize = 200);
const inputStream = fs.createReadStream('test.xml');
const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('test1.xml');

inputStream.pipe(xmlsplit).pipe(outputStream).on('data', function (data) {
    let xmlDocument = data.toString();

})
```

Comment: `batchSize=200` is pretty big depending on how your XML looks like. With given `batchSize` you want each file to contain 200 xml items.

Comment: The file looks like:

 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1">
<item>
 <prod_id>1</prod_id>
 <prod_amount>1</prod_amount>
</item>
<item>
 <prod_id>2</prod_id>
 <prod_amount>3</prod_amount>
</item>`

I have for example file where is 5000 <item> and i want to split it into multiple files which each contain 200 <item>

Comment: if what you want is to reduce memory usage, you can use any sax parser.